# iOS Google Drive sdk Integration & Permission

Tags: iphone, ios, google-drive-api, google-api-objc-client

Actually i followed this link [google drive sdk for develoeprs](https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/objectivec)

And i configured all things what they mentioned in the above link. But the problem i am facing was the sample app DrEdit was not listing the text files on ios simulator after logged in and after i gave the permission "Allow Access" even i am having some text files in my google drive. Any thing i did wring here?. My another doubt was why there is a difference between DocuDign Ink ios app permissions and DrEdit app permissions. Please check the screen shots here i attached one i took it from DrEdit from simulator and another one from DocuSign Ink ios app from my iPad.[image: DrEdit Google Drive sdk permisson page]
[image: DocuSign Ink Google Drive SDK permisson page]
**Note:**
DrEdit app shows the permissions: "View and manage Google Drive files that you have opened or created with this app". But I would like to see the permission like this: "view and manage any of your documents and files in Google Drive". How and where I can change the permission?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DrEdit uses the limited `drive.file` scope that only allows it to access files that it created or that the user opened with it.

DocuSign instead requests the full `drive` scope that allows the app to manage all user's Drive files.

It is strongly recommended to request the limited scope when possible. For more details about all available scopes, check the Google Drive SDK documentation:

https://developers.google.com/drive/scopes